# Как можно скрывать view в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Добрый день. Есть листинг основанный на RecyclerView. Есть необходимость  при выборе в меню, скрывать или отображать часть строк. Адаптер наследую от  RecyclerView.Adapte.

Есть ли элегантный способ сделать это. В данный момент приходится хранить копию коллекции и уже в ней удалять компоненты и пересоздавать адаптер.

Comment: Скрываемые строки расположены рандомно или подряд в начале/конце списка?

Comment: рандомно, для объктов с определенными свойствами

Comment: Тогда Ваше решение и есть правильное, только адаптер пересоздавать не нужно, достаточно отфильтровать рабочую коллекцию и вызвать `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

По идее можно просто корневому `View` нужных ячеек выставить `setVisibility(View.GONE)` или `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` в `onBindViewHolder` в зависимости от некоторого условия, определяемого Вами. После каждого изменения данного условия необходимо вызывать `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: я так пробовал, но есть проблема, в том что исчезают, но остальные не сдвигаются. Получается старый лист с кучей дырок в экране.